# Is there any public API which give the steps of solving derivative questions( Calculus)?

Tags: api, calculator, derivative, calculus

I want to make a scientific calculator for calculating derivatives.
I want to show the steps of the solution.
I have tried to get some API that provides me with the steps of solving the Derivative Questions but have not succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

I found an [Api](https://products.wolframalpha.com/api) to solve the calculus questions, but it is not giving a proper response on my end.
May it work for you.